# How to force the signal.sawtooth to start by 0?

Tags: python, scipy, signals

it might be a simple trick, but I don't get it right away. I would like the sawtooth signal to start by (0,0) and go up for a 1/4th of a period so like a sinus would do instead of starting by (0,-1).

```
    from scipy import signal
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    t = np.linspace(0, 1, 500)
    plt.plot(t, signal.sawtooth(2 * np.pi * 5 * t))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delay the phase by `pi`

```
from scipy import signal
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
t = np.linspace(0, 1, 500)
plt.plot(t, signal.sawtooth(2 * np.pi * 5 * t-np.pi))
plt.show()
```

Just add `-np.pi` term in the argument

Comment: Thank you, I will try that!